# How can I call my connection variable from another class?

Tags: java, sql, class, variables, connection

```
private static Connection conexion() {
    try {

        //Cargamos el Driver MySQL

        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(server, user, pass);


     } catch (Exception e) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error "+e);
         System.out.println("SQLException: " + e.getMessage());
         System.out.println("SQLState: " + ((SQLException) e).getSQLState());
         System.out.println("VendorError: " + ((SQLException) e).getErrorCode());
     }
     return conexion;

}
```

That's where I create my connection. How do I call that variable from other classes without creating new connections? I don't want to make multiple connections, I want to use the same connection for my entire Java program.

Is there a way to call that variable? I'm a new programmer.

Comment: You don't call things from classes. You call things from methods. Your other objects need to have references to the object that hold the connection.

Comment: I'm no expert in java but normaly the connection have the the close after each query.

Comment: I would highly suggest starting with a good beginner's book on Java or the Tutorials provided by Oracle.

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is the Singleton design pattern, where you only have one object created at any given time.  There is a good write-up on Wikipedia, but be careful as there are some considerations when implementing it in a Java application that is using threading:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do something like this

```
private Connection conn;

public Connection getConn(){
    if(conn == null || conn.isClosed)
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(server, user, pass);
    return conn;
}
```

in the class you gonna use the connection... you always need to close the connection it´s a good practice and your database gonna thank you

Comment: So I do that in every class?

Comment: @Adrian you should do a class like this                             `public class Conexion
{                                                                                     private static Connection conn;

public static Connection getConn(){
    if(conn == null || conn.isClosed)
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(server, user, pass);
    return conn;
}}`  and in the class you gonna use the connection `public class MyClass extends Conexion{ Connection conn = getConn();`